# g++ undefined reference to while linking with a custom shared library

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries, ld, undefined-reference

I am trying to link my C++ program with a custom shared library. The shared library is written in C, however, I don't think that it should matter. My library is called `libfoo.so`. Its full path is `/home/xyz/customlib/libfoo.so`. I've also added `/home/xyz/customlib` to my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` so `ld` should be able to find it. When I run `nm -D libfoo.so`, I get:

```
...
00000000000053a1 T myfunc
000000000000505f T foo
0000000000004ca9 T bar
00000000000051c6 T baz
000000000000527f T myfunc2
...
```

So I think that my library is correctly compiled. I am trying to link it my c++ file `test.cpp` by running

```
g++ -L/home/xyz/customlib -Og -g3 -ggdb -fsanitize=address test.cpp -o test -lfoo
```

However, I am getting the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: in function sharedlib_test1()
/home/xyz/test.cpp:11: undefined reference to `myfunc()'
/usr/bin/ld: in function sharedlib_test2()
/home/xyz/test.cpp:33: undefined reference to `foo()'
...
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I resolve this? Note that I have renamed the files and the shared library as I cannot share the exact file and function names.

Comment: ¿Are imported functions declared as `extern "C"`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: Regarding : "The shared library is written in C, however, I don't think that it should matter", you generally need to make sure the functions are declared as "extern C" in headers.

Comment: To expand on this a little bit.... Normally a dual-use C/C++ library will use `#ifdef __cplusplus` pre-processor directive, and then `extern "C"` around the entire header if true.  But if you can't/don't want to modify the C-library header, you can also wrap the `#include` within your CPP source in `extern "C"`.  good to be familiar with both methods if you're doing language mix & match.

Comment: I was missing the extern "C". Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by the comments in the post, it turns out that I was missing the extern "C" in the header file. So in my code, I wrapped my include statement in an extern "C" which solved the issue.

TLDR: The header include in the code should look like:

```
extern "C"      // Import C style functions 
{
        #include <foo.h>
}
```